# How do I remove white space and blank sides in Flash movies?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I use Flash Pro CS5 to create new movies and modify old movies.

When I publish the movie I developed it comes with two white blank sides. I've tried to change the publish settings like Dimensions and Scale and publish the flash movie but the white blank sides did not disappear.

I want the flash movie to have all of the space of the display window so that no white space appears when I view it in normal or maximized or full-screen view modes.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;
```

It will scale your content to fill the space but it will maintain the aspect ratio so content will be cropped that goes beyond the viewable area.

or

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

Will scale your content to fill the space with out maintaining the aspect ratio so images will become skewed.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html